# 60s/70s song, lyrics "Sweet my little baby", possibly Led Zeppelin

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics, led-zeppelin

The song is very close to what Led Zeppelin sounds like. If it helps I will try to explain what some of the non words sounds sound like with 0 to 10 with 0 being lowest pitch you can commonly find in songs, it goes with a guitar strumming at about 1.5 seconds each note I guess you would say, 6-3-5-3, then faster notes that have higher pitch at around a 8.

Some lyrics I can remember (some of these words are words that rhyme or sound like the correct version of the word) : "Sweet my little baby what did I do wrong."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Sweet little baby" is a recurrent lyric in Led Zeppelin's song "Dazed and Confused" song from their 1969 Album "Led Zeppelin".
That's about as far as I can get to identify the song you are looking for.

Comment: This is a pretty amazing answer given how little detail you had to go on. :)

Comment: Haha, thank you. I'm a big fan of 60-70's rock (especially Led Zeppelin). When I read "sweet my little baby" I knew what song it could be.